# Plotting Latent Trajectory (HLME)

Tags: r, plot

I am new to RStudio, and am having trouble plotting the mean predicted trajectories over time for a single latent variable.

My dataset is called "longform" and I ran a model predicting latent groups of a psychological construct (Selfreliance) over 7 waves of data collection (time variable - wave; respondents - ID.)

Here is my original code for the non-conditional model:
m1 <- hlme(selfreliance ~ wave, subject = "ID", random=~1 + wave, ng = 1, data = longform)

I am able to run a diagnostic plot of residuals: plot(m1)

However, I would like to visualize the latent trajectory. I run the following command, and receive the following error:

plot(m1, which = "fit", var.time = "wave")
Error in xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.